# how to output first line from every file in linux?

Tags: linux

I like to output only the first line from each and every single file in `/etc` and redirect stdout to a .txt file and redirect stderr to another file.

How can i do it?

So far, I tried,

```
head -1 /etc > file 2> file2 ?
```

Comment: something like `find /etc -type f -exec head -1 {} \; >outp 2>sterr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`head` has the `-q` option which suppresses the headers:

```
head -q -n1 /etc/* > file 2> err
```

`err` will contain mostly `is a directory` warnings.

Comment: tyvm, i knew somehow i was thinking i had to use globbing on this task, but  I didn't know how. but thanks!